# Custom jersey Inflector

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm building a RESTful service where endpoints are supposed to be generated based on resource file description. 
Registering resources with implicit method builder handler works just fine, however when I try to replace implicit handler with explicit I'm hitting a wall.

In the example below I've replaced implicit handler Inflector with explicit ItemInflector implementation. String result is expected after execution.

```
final Resource.Builder resourceBuilder = Resource.builder();
resourceBuilder.path("api/myservice/item");
final ResourceMethod.Builder methodBuilder = resourceBuilder.addMethod("GET");

methodBuilder.produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
    .handledBy(new ItemInflector<ContainerRequestContext, String>(String.class));

final Resource resource = resourceBuilder.build();
registerResources(resource);
```

ItenInflector implementation:

```
public class ItemInflector<DATA extends ContainerRequestContext, RESULT> implements Inflector<DATA, RESULT> {

    private Class<RESULT> type;

    public ItemInflector(Class<RESULT> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public RESULT apply(DATA data) {
        return type.cast("Half programmatically generated endpoint");
    }
}
```

At runtime the following error is thrown when I try to hit endpoint.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type parameter RESULT not a class or parameterized type whose raw type is a class
```

Could someone clear out what am I doing wrong in the Inflector implementation? 
How to parametrize or define RESULT type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type parameter (`<ContainerRequestContext, String>`), specified during the `ItemInflector` instance creation, is lost at runtime. The reason is Javas [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) behaviour. You have to specify the type in a subclass or use anonymous classes here.

*option 1, anonymous class (yes, now the compiler keeps the type information):*

```
methodBuilder.produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
    .handledBy(new Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, String>(){
        ...
    });
```

*option 2, specify type in a sublcass:*

```
public class ItemInflector implements Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, String> {
....
}
```

Here is a very detailed information regarding type erasure behaviour: [Java generics - type erasure - when and what happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

Comment: Would you mind to update the second links, it's broken.